# Norm/Mesh of partitions in multiple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

[image]

Here, $||P||$ is the norm of the partition which is defined by $max${$\Delta x,\Delta y$}, i.e., the maximum of either side of each **sub-rectangle**. Why can we not define $||P||$ as $max${$\Delta x \Delta y$}? Can someone provide a counter-example of a function explaining why the following assumption as the *norm* fails in certain cases? I was told that the **Darboux Integral** failed to hold for certain *integrable* functions for the above assumed *norm*. Also, can we not define $||P||$ as the length of the **largest diagonal** of all such **sub-rectangles**? Would there be any problem in that case?

Comment: Using the diagonal is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x,y) =x$ on the rectangle $[0,1]^2$, where

$$\int_{[0,1]^2} f = \frac{1}{2}$$

Let the partition $P_n$ have subrectangles $[0,1]\times [(j-1)/n,j/n]$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. The upper Darboux sum $U(P_n,f)$ remains constant with value $1$ even as $n \to \infty$ and does not converge to the integral.  However, the norm of the partition defined as the maximum area of subrectangles is $1/n$ and tends to $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! By the way, we'd be obtaining $1/2$ as our answer using tagged partitions and not the upper sum, right?

Comment: @AbhinavTahlani: You're welcome.  The upper sum here is a Riemann sum with a tagged partition.  The function is continuous and monotone in $x$ so the supremum is attained at the boundary of a subrectangle.  Even without that a sequence of upper sums will converge to the integral as the (correct) partition norm tends to $0$. For a Riemann integrable function, the integral is the infimum of Darboux upper sums over all partitions.